# Prevent django formset submission if empty

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that I only want users to be able to submit if a field in a formset is filled. This is a dynamic formset in which users can add and remove rows, I want it so that at least one row needs to have an entry in it. However it seems that the formset is able to be submitted even if not valid.

For example if the user does not put an entry for 'age' a popup will request that they enter something. This does not occur for 'diagnosis'

models.py

```
class Patient(TimeStampedModel):
    patient_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    
    age = models.IntegerField("Age")

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    
class Diagnosis(TimeStampedModel):
    
    DIAG_CHOICES = [
        (‘heart’, (
                (‘mi’, ‘heart attack’),
                (‘chf’, ‘heart failure’),
            )
        ),
        (‘kidney’, (
                (‘arf’, ‘acute renal failure’),
                (‘crf’, ‘chronic renal failure’),
            )
        ),
        ]
    
    diag_name = models.CharField(
        "diag", max_length=200,
        choices=DIAG_CHOICES, blank=False)

    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['age']


DiagnosisFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Patient, Diagnosis, fields=("diag_name", ), extra=0, min_num=1, validate_min=True)
```

views.py

```
class PatientAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    model = Patient
    template_name = "../templates/patient/add.html"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        patient_form = PatientForm
        diagnosis_formset = DiagnosisFormSet(queryset=Diagnosis.objects.none())

        return self.render_to_response({'diagnosis_formset': diagnosis_formset,
                                        'patient_form': patient_form
                                })

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PatientForm(data=self.request.POST)
        diagnosis_formset = DiagnosisFormSet(data=self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            patient_instance = form.save()
            patient_instance.user = self.request.user
            patient_instance.save()

            if diagnosis_formset.is_valid():
                diag_name = diagnosis_formset.save(commit=False)
                for diag in diag_name:
                    diag.patient = patient_instance
                    diag.save()
          

        return redirect(reverse(
                        'patient:treatment_detail',
                        kwargs={"patient_id": patient_instance.patient_id}))
```

Comment: check `validate_min` + `min_num` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#validate-min

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko many thanks, I think I was not clear initially - my problem is that the user is able to submit the form even if the diagnosis formset is invalid (i.e. even if I set validate_min=True, and min_num=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select    

DiagnosisFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Patient, Diagnosis, fields=("diag_name",), extra=1, min_num=1, validate_min=True,
        widgets={
            'diag_name': Select(attrs={'required': 'required'}),
        },
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add an "else" condition when checking "diagnosis_formset.is_valid()"

```
if diagnosis_formset.is_valid():
    diag_name = diagnosis_formset.save(commit=False)
    for diag in diag_name:
    diag.patient = patient_instance
    diag.save()
else:
     render (self.request,"../templates/patient/add.html",{'diagnosis_formset': diagnosis_formset,
                                    'patient_form': form})
```

Comment: This does not have the desired effect the form can still be submitted

Comment: the form will be submitted , but user is sent back to the form and an error message "This filed is required" will be displayed.  Is this not happening?

Comment: No, the return statement still completes ( return redirect(reverse('patient:treatment_detail'). Also what I would ideally like to happen is what occurs if 'age' is not filled in - the user unable to submit the form and the required entry box is highlighted.

Comment: added one more answer , try that , but it will make all rows in Diagnosis form to be filled , not just one